# Редактирование datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

чувствую себя совсем тупым. не могу сделать редактируемую таблицу. Пожалуйста распишите процесс создания редактируемой таблицы datagrid!

Answer (score 5):

Вам бы для начала понять принципы MVVM, как работает WPF приложение и что такое C# язык в целом.

Ну а так, вот вам простейший пример реализации редактируемой таблицы в WPF с паттерном MVVM:

1. Добавляем вспомогательный класс для реализации ICommand. У всех своя реализация, я возьму эту:

   ```
   public class RelayCommand : ICommand
   {
       private Action action;
       public RelayCommand(Action action) => this.action = action;
       public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
       #pragma warning disable CS0067
       public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
       #pragma warning restore CS0067
       public void Execute(object parameter) => action();
   }
   ```
2. Дальше нам понадобится ViewModel нашего внутреннего объекта. Я буду писать стандартную информацию про человека (имя, фамилия и возраст). В WPF привязка идет к свойствам (не полям), так давайте сделаем необходимые свойства, а для удобства мы будем их заполнять через конструктор:

   ```
   public class PersonViewModel
   {
       public PersonViewModel(string firstName, string lastName, int age)
       {
           FirstName = firstName;
           LastName = lastName;
           Age = age;
       }

       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Хорошо, имея все это можем сделать основную ViewModel нашего приложения, в ней должна быть реализована коллекция, которая будет оповещать интерфейс об изменении (в wpf из коробки этим обладают `ObservableCollection` и `BindingList`. Также нам надо реализовать команды (в MVVM паттерне не принято использовать `click` события.), которые будут показывать информацию выбранного объекта, а также добавлять новый. Так, как нам нужно знать об выбранной строке, сделаем свойство и для этого:

   ```
   public class MainViewModel
   {
       public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> Persons { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>();
       public PersonViewModel SelectedPerson { get; set; }

       public ICommand AddRowCommand { get; set; }
       public ICommand GetRowInfoCommand { get; set; }

       public MainViewModel()
       {
           AddRowCommand = new RelayCommand(AddRow);
           GetRowInfoCommand = new RelayCommand(GetRowInfo);
       }

       private void AddRow() => Persons.Add(new PersonViewModel("Вася", "Пупкин", 13));

       private void GetRowInfo()
       {
           if (SelectedPerson != null)
               MessageBox.Show($"Имя: {SelectedPerson.FirstName}\nФамилия: {SelectedPerson.LastName}\nВозраст: {SelectedPerson.Age}");
       }
   }
   ```

   Обратите внимание! Я тут вызываю для наглядности `MessageBox.Show`, в MVVM это не очень хороший подход!
4. Ну и остается View, то есть наш XAML. Я сделаю grid, который разделит нашу область на 2 части, в верхнюю помещаю DataGrid, которой разрешено редактировать, добавлять новый и все другие требования, а также привязываю ItemsSource и SelectedItem. В низ я помещаю две кнопки по центру, им задаю текст и привязку у командам:

   ```
   <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition/>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True"/>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
           <Button Content="Добавить" Margin="2" Command="{Binding AddRowCommand}"/>
           <Button Content="Информация" Margin="2" Command="{Binding GetRowInfoCommand}"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
   ```
5. Остается задать DataContext. Я буду делать чуть не правильно (по правилам он должен быть на уровне выше, к примеру в App), здесь же я сделаю прям в MainWindow:

   ```
   private MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; } = new MainViewModel();
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataContext = MainViewModel;
   }
   ```

Вот и все, простейшая реализация DataGrid по всем правилам WPF. Давайте взглянем на результат:

[image: Result]